# @njit issues with iterable definition for min function

Tags: python, list, min, numba

I am trying to define an `@njit` function which at several points needs to calculate the minimum. Doing this as follows works:

```
min(arg1, arg2,...)
```

However when I go to calculate the minimum of an iterable I seem to have a problem no matter how that iterable is defined. I've reproduced this with a small function below:

```
itrbl = [5.0, 0.4, 4.5, 3.5, 6.4]

@njit
def funct(itrbl):
    return min(itrbl)

funct(itrbl)
```

and get the following error:

```
TypingError: Invalid usage of Function(<built-in function min>) with parameters (reflected list(float64))
  * parameterized
```

It doesn't seem to like when I structure `itrbl` as an array either... How do I need to structure `itrbl` to make this simple function work?

Comment: you should try to use numpy arrays.

Comment: If I convert irtbl to a numpy array 'itrbl=np.array([5.0, 0.4, 4.5, 3.5, 6.4])' I get the error 'Invalid usage of Function(<built-in function min>) with parameters (array(float64, 1d, C))
 * parameterized'

Comment: Does it work with numpy's min function?

Comment: Yes. It does. Thanks @pbreach. 

So I just need a numpy array with np.min to calculate the minimum of an iterable, and I can use the builtin min function to calculate the minimum of several args.

Comment: Using a tuple works with `min`, so `itrbl = (5.0, 0.4, 4.5, 3.5, 6.4)`.

Answer (score 0):

In an `njit`ted function the function calls are replaced by numba versions of these functions. So when you call `min` it's not Pythons `min` function.

Also numba is generally optimized for working with `numpy.array`s not `list`s. When you pass in a `list` to a numba `njit`ted function (from Python) or return a `list` from a `njit`ted function (to Python) it has to convert (copy) the whole list to a reflected list or the other way around when returning ([Why is passing a list (of length n) to a numba nopython function an O(n) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44489126/5393381)). So you should avoid passing Python lists to numba functions or returning them. However creating a list in a numba function and passing it to other numba functions doesn't suffer from this conversion overhead.

But that's a bit besides the point of the actual question regarding `list` and `min` in a numba function. It looks like the numba-version of `min` doesn't support lists/arrays (but it does support tuples).

You could easily create a numba function that supports lists:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def my_min(lst):
    "Don't pass empty arrays/lists to this function!"
    min_ = lst[0]
    for item in lst:
        if item < min_:
            min_ = item
    return min_
```

Which seems to work:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def funct(itrbl):
    return my_min(itrbl)

>>> funct([5.0, 0.4, 4.5, 3.5, 6.4])
0.4
```

However the better approach would be to use `array`s in the number functions. The reason is that in my experience with numba you often reach cases where numba doesn't support lists (like with `min`) or calling the method on lists is comparatively slow. Also the overhead of passing lists to numba functions or returning them from numba functions can be enormous (and unexpected).